# Why does it take 5-10 minutes to mount an external HDD?

Tags: mount, external-hdd, automount

I Have an external HDD drive (USB 3.0, 750Gb) almost full.

When I connect it to a USB Port in my laptop (USB 3.0 or USB 2.0), it takes forever mounting it (like 5 to 10 minutes) but finally does it.

Perhaps, does it perform a full scan of it before mounting it?

Answer (score 0):

5-10 minutes seems *exceedingly* slow!

1. Do you have USB Legacy support turned on in your BIOS? (If yes, turn off!)
2. Can you provide the output for:

   ```
   fdisk -l
   df --human
   ```

Comment: No, he can't. :)